# single sql insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table A
Column

```
1.Int 
2.Name          
3.Int1
4.Name1
```

Table B
Column

```
1.Int  
2.Name
```

How to insert table A all column to table B column in single query.?

Answer (score 4):

if i understand what you need is : [insert select command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO  b (col1,col2)
SELECT col1,col2 FROM a 
UNION ALL
SELECT col3,col4 FROM a
```

Comment: working . then column is diffrent datatype . same query working?

Comment: As long as the data types are compatible and everything fits it won't matter, but if you try to insert an varchar into a datetime format... That will not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO B (Int, Name)
SELECT
  CASE x.f WHEN 0 THEN A.Int  ELSE A.Int1  END,
  CASE x.f WHEN 0 THEN A.Name ELSE A.Name1 END
FROM A
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS f UNION ALL SELECT 1) x
```

The approach is basically described [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/will-somebody-optimize-this-sql-query/2761#2761).

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO  table1 (field1, field2) SELECT field1, field2 FROM table2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--insert the all columns record from table A to table B

INSERT INTO  tableB ([Int], [Name]) 
SELECT [Int], [Name] FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT [Int1], [Name1] FROM tableA
```